# How do I use Chrome's device toolbar?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

1. I've been trying to figure out if, for example, when you click on 'iPhone X' it actually gives you the real dimensions of the iPhone X. By real, I mean physically putting my phone against my laptop screen. My guesstimate now is that it doesn't give the real dimensions. Does it just give the real x-axis y-axis px ratio?
2. I can see the x-axis y-axis px in the upper-bar. That makes sense. But what is the `%` for? 100% is 100% of what? Is this true: at 100%, what Chrome reports viewport height & width to be is what it actually is on my screen (e.g. at 100%, Chrome says the device is 320px across the way & Mac's ruler, generated with `Cmd + shift + 4`, shows the device to be 320px wide).

Comment: Maybe reading this will help you. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode. Matching physical size with the real device is a coincidence based on the display you're using.

Answer (score 0):

1. It does not give the "real dimensions" of the device. To the best of my knowledge, the browser cannot access information on the pixel density of the device it is running on, so even if some product manager on the chrome team was interested in implementing this feature, it is not possible.
2. It's simply the zoom level in the browser - content layout does not change based on what value is selected.